# Cannot print the FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString in my iOS9 app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-access-token

I was creating an app in Swift for iOS 9 for learning purposes. I was trying to print the current access Token of Facebook at time when I log into Facebook through my app.

When I click the fblogin button it opens Safari and shows me that I already have authorized my app but when I click okay it stuck on the Safari page and doesn't print the token as it should. And it says :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am using XCode 7.3.1. I am adding the pic of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might be that at this point in the completion handler, the `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` isn't saved yet, that's why it's still `nil`.
You can use the `@property (copy, nonatomic) FBSDKAccessToken *token;` property on `FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult`:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) in
  if let token = facebookResult.token.tokenString {
    print(token)
  }
}
```

Comment: can  you please explain and show the code in little bit detail that would be very helpfull

Comment: See my edit, just take the token from the login result. Be aware that it's optional so take care unwrapping.

Comment: it says : Value of type 'FBSDKLoginManager' has no member 'loginWithReadPermissions'

Comment: Don't just copy and paste, try to understand. I've typo in the method name it's logIn with capital I

Comment: thanks for your help the last thing i want to ask you can u please suggest some source from where I can learn ios properly. All i learning from some basic video tutorial :( and once again thank  you for your help.. I am understanding it clearly... :)

Comment: Start with Stanford courses on iTunesU. But this is irrelevant for this thread. Try to give feedback whether my suggestion helped.