# Firebase(url:"") function is not working

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, cocoapods, firebase-realtime-database

I have installed the firebase pod in my project and imported Firebase to my swift class but when i am trying to implement Firebase(url:"") function its not working  it says :

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'module Firebase'

I am using xcode 7.3.1

there is the pic of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Firebase you are using?
I'm assuming 3.0+, so you'll need to get the reference as follow:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Edit:
Make sure to add `pod 'Firebase/Database'` in your podfile and then `import FirebaseDatabase`

Comment: i am using firebase 3.2.1 now and do i have to write the ulr in the reference brakects?

Comment: No, that's all you need to get a reference to your firebase database. See the new firebase tutorials: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Comment: I have another question can you please check the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031044/can-not-print-the-fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-tokenstring-in-my-ios9-a

Comment: FIRDatabase is not showing :( although i have updated everything

Comment: Please see my edit. Also i really encourage you to go over the full getting start tutorial from Firebase.

Comment: yep I am going through the new docs for ios in firebase documentation and thanks for your help.. really appreciated

Comment: by the way I am a newbee so can please suggest  me some good source to learn ios programming in swift